# Custom Functions and accessing specific cells based on the location of the function

Tags: google-apps-script, custom-function

This community has been very helpful to me before and I am looking for answers again.  I want to build a function that I can create once and drag-copy like the example below.

```
Jan Mon 1       "=CustomFunction()" -->Jan 1
Feb Tue 2       "=CustomFunction()" -->Feb 2
Mar Wed 3       "=CustomFunction()" -->Mar 3
```

I want the function to look for specific information in a specified column on IT'S specific row.  Will .getActiveRange() accomplish this task and treat the function as the "active cell"?

I have not yet started the coding for this because I honestly do not know where to start with it.

Thank you again for your attention and assistance with this.

Comment: If you are just going to convert the data of format `Jan Mon 1` to this format `Jan 1`. You don't have to use google app scripts, you can just use [sheet Functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en) to do it! You might wanna look at `Left()`, `right()` and `concat()` functions.

Comment: I guess using months and days muddled the example a bit.  I should have used random variables.  What I am trying to get done (without having to manually select every cell in the calculation) is to put a =customerfunction() in lets say D4 and it automatically know that I want to use the data in the 4th row from columns 1 and 3 to make a calculation. But, the same =CustomerFunction(), if put in D5 would automatically know that the calculations of the function need to be performed with the data on the 5th row but still columns 1 and 3.  Does this make sense?